# 100% Height div, scrollbars 50px off screen due to margin-top 50px. overflow auto

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to layout a page that has a horizontal navigation bar across the top and content area that will gain scrollbars when the content is too big.

My current way of doing this is a div width 100%; height 50px; position absolute; top 0; left 0; and then a second div with height 100%; width 100%; margin-top 50px; overflow:auto; however, the scrollbar that appears is offset by the 50px margin and as such pushes the content off the bottom of the page. If i remove the margin it all works but it puts the content behind the navigation bar.

I also tried wrapping it in a container an experimenting with putting the margin their and the overflow in the child but this still didn't seem to have the required effect.

jsFiddle, with comments to try explain it better.

http://jsfiddle.net/Piercy/hggXJ/

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
  <h1>Navigation</h1>
</div>
<!-- <div id="contentContainer"> -->
  <div id="content">
    <div id="oversizeContent">
        <p>You can see the black border on this green box, but you cannot see the bottom black border. Similarly you cannot see the bottom arrow of the scrollbar.</p>
        <p>I tried putting a wrapper around the content and putting the margin on that but the scrollbar still over flows  Uncomment the contentContainer div and comment/uncomment the corresponding  css.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- <div> -->
```

CSS

```
html, body
{
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
}

#nav
{
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index: 2;
}
#contentContainer
{
  /* uncomment this if you bring #contentContainer into play */
  /* 
      margin-top:50px;
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;   
  */


  height:100%;
  width:100%; 

}
#content
{
  /* moving this into #contentContainer doesnt help either */
  /* comment this if you bring #contentContainer into play */

      margin-top:50px;
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;



  width:100%;
  height:100%;

  background-color:blue;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
#oversizeContent 
{
  background-color:green;
  width:400px;
  height:1000px;
  border:10px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `#oversizeContent { margin-bottom: 50px; }` to fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

instead of `height:100%;` do `bottom:0;` and it will go to the bottom of the relative parent or viewport if there is no container set to `position:relative;`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hggXJ/2/)

Comment: i had to keep the margin-top but adding bottom:0; and removing the height:100%; seemed to do it! thanks, http://jsfiddle.net/Piercy/E69TZ/1/

Comment: Glad to help! ^_^  ... if you have absolutely positioned elements it often comes really handy to use top, bottom, left and right instead of height and width properties.

Comment: I also had to do "position: fixed" instead of absolute so that 100% height content won't get scrolled off the window if the main page has scroll bar.